# Intuition of different products of tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, inner-products, tensor-products, tensors

Two tensors of different ranks can be multiplied in two ways:

- Outer product: Like $A^{ijk}_{lm}B^{r}_s=C^{ijkr}_{lms}$ is the outer product of $A^{ijk}_{lm}$ and $B^{r}_s$
- Inner product: (outer product of two tensors followed by a contraction) $A^{ij}_k$ and $B^{l}_{mn}$ is $A^{ij}_kB^{l}_{mn}\stackrel{k=l}{=}A^{ij}_lB^{l}_{mn}$

> contraction: If in a mixed tensor, we put one contravariant and one covariant index equal, and the sum is performed over that repeated index, then a new tensor of the lower order is obtained. $A^{ijk}_{pq}\stackrel{q=k}{=}B^{ij}_p\stackrel{p=j}{=}C^i$

I am confused about these products. Why is such a product needed in tensor, or how is it related to our usual product (from inner product space)?

The Outer product makes some sense, but I couldn't make sense of the inner products. Like why here contraction was introduced without any context?

Comment: The first product looks like the tensor product, wirtten $C = A \otimes B$. I'm not sure about the second one, but contraction is also called the trace operator. Importantly, both tensor product and trace are defined invariantly, so the same formula works in any coordinates you choose. Lots of important tensors can be written using these operations.

Comment: **Lots of important tensors can be written using these operations.** If you don't mind, can you give an example? @Mason And thanks for your response

Comment: $\text{div} X = \text{Tr} \nabla X$ when $X$ is a vector field. This becomes the definition of divergence for when $X$ is a $(k, \ell)$ tensor field. The $dx^{i_1} \otimes \dots \otimes d^{x_\ell}$ form a basis for the $\ell$ covariant tensors at a point. In calculations, the coordinates of your tensor are usually expressed with respect to this basis, e.g. $g = g_{ij}dx^{i} \otimes dx^{j}$. And there are "product rule" type identites for various differentiation operators with respect to the tensor product, like for $\nabla_{X}$ and $L_X$.

Comment: But I think the main benefit of defining these operations is that they are "coordinate free", which means that the same formula can be used to compute them in any coordinates. The more things that you know are coordinate free, the easier your computations can be, because you are free to choose really nice coordinates, like exponential coordinates.